# No keyword with name 'Fetch From Left' found

Tags: csv, robotframework

I'm automating with robot framework but I'm getting this error

```
No keyword with name 'Fetch From Left' found.
```

I don't understand the cause, I'm new in this tool

Here is my code:

```
${FILE_RUTS_INFORMACION_PERSONAL}          archivo2.csv
```

Im reading CSV file with three DNI

```
Carga RUTs
    [Documentation]      Carga lista de RUTs a validar desde archivo csv
    [Arguments]              ${file_name}

    ${data}=                 read csv file       ${file_name}
    [return]    ${data}
```

Here is the error:

```
Consultar WS
    [Documentation]       Lee RUTs de archivo csv y consulta cada uno al Experto Original y Migrado.
    [Arguments]           ${data}

    ${rutsd}=       Set Variable        0
    ${dv} =         Set Variable        0

    Log To Console         .
    :FOR   ${element}        IN        ${data}
    \      ${rutsd}=        Fetch From Left          @{element}[0]       ;
    \      ${dvymas}=       Get Substring            @{element}[0]       -1
    \      ${dv}=           Fetch From Left          ${dvymas}           ;

    \      Log To Console      Consultando RUT ${rutsd}...
    \      Run Keyword And Continue On Failure        WS Experto Orignal       ${rutsd}     ${dv}
```

ERROR:

```
FOR ${element} IN [ ${data} ]
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170823 10:00:11.149 / 20170823 10:00:11.151 / 00:00:00.002
00:00:00.002VAR ${element} = [['169233xxx;'], ['169129xxx;'], ['189925xxx;']]
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170823 10:00:11.149 / 20170823 10:00:11.151 / 00:00:00.002
00:00:00.000KEYWORD ${rutsd}= = Fetch From Left @{element}[0], ;
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170823 10:00:11.151 / 20170823 10:00:11.151 / 00:00:00.000
10:00:11.151    FAIL    No keyword with name 'Fetch From Left' found.
```

Comment: Why do you think there should be a keyword named `Fetch from left`? Did you create a keyword with that name? Are you importing a library which contains that keyword? If so, what library?

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the [String library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html). See the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#importing-libraries) for more information. Only the BuiltIn library doesn't need to be imported. Looking at the code you posted, you don't seem to be importing it.

Adding this to your settings section should do the trick

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String
```